# Edit file and save in another app

Tags: java, android, file

I have a question:

The scenario is:

1 - I have a file in my app with docx extension(which is on the server)
2 - I want to open this file in my android in an office app
3 - I edit the file in an ms office app or google docs
4 - when I close the app(MSoffice or docs) after editing the changes will be reflected in the file in my app.
5 - I can update the server accordingly when the file being edited.

Its same like Dropbox does.

Please show me the way to achieve this.
Thank you

Comment: write more details about how the user can use this application.

Comment: I have a file on the server, I open this in my app, my app redirects me to MS word or any other app that can open this file, now I made changes in this file. How my app will know what changes are made in the file?